# DynamoDB: Avoid duplicating data in many-to-many relationship

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries

I am practicing DynamoDB applying STD (single table design) and I am having some troubles to design my scheme.

Given the simple many-to-many relationship "A Club can have N players while a player can play in M clubs".
And supposing the following two AP (access patterns):

1. Get all the players from a Club.
2. Get all clubs where a player plays.

The AP 1 can be solved by the following schema:

[image]

Pseudo-Query:

```
GET * WHERE PK = 'CLUB#C1'
```

However, I am not figuring a good way to solve the AP 2. I could a GSI and have the following new scheme:

[image]

But, despite I can get the Clubs IDs, I am not retrieving the Club's information.

I have read AWS's dcumentation [the Adjacency list design pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html)
[image]

But, as far as I understand, it is quite different from my example since it is not querying Invoice's specific information for each bill.
In my case, I do need the Club's specific information shared by all players.

The only way I have figured out to do so (in a single query) is: for each Club-Player relation, store both entities' information.

Considering that both Club and Player have not static data that may change over time, how would I handle updates? Is it expected to do N updates each time an attribute change?

Answer (score 1):

You can't always expect to get all of the data with a single lookup. You want all the clubs that a player plays for, which you can get from your GSI. Then you have 2 choices, wait until a user clicks on a club at fetch that information with a GetItem, or load all the clubs needed beforehand with a BatchGetItem.